# Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.Instant` - jackson

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

Having class like this

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public final class ActiveRecoveryProcess {

    private UUID recoveryId;
    private Instant startedAt;
}
```

I'm getting `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException` with message `Cannot deserialize value of type`java.time.Instant`from String "2020-02-22T16:37:23": Failed to deserialize java.time.Instant: (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) Text '2020-02-22T16:37:23' could not be parsed at index 19`

JSON input

```
{"startedAt": "2020-02-22T16:37:23", "recoveryId": "6f6ee3e5-51c7-496a-b845-1c647a64021e"}
```

Jackson configuration

```
    @Autowired
    void configureObjectMapper(final ObjectMapper mapper) {
        mapper.registerModule(new ParameterNamesModule())
                .registerModule(new Jdk8Module())
                .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        mapper.findAndRegisterModules();
    }
```

EDIT

JSON is generated from postgres

```
jsonb_build_object(
                        'recoveryId', r.recovery_id,
                        'startedAt', r.started_at
)
```

where `r.started_at` is TIMESTAMP.

Comment: `Instant` is being used over the whole project. Why should I consider using `LocalDateTime` over `Instant`?

Comment: If the incoming data just says `2020-02-22T16:37:23`, without a `Z` at the end, how do you know *for sure* that the time is in UTC? Perhaps using `LocalDateTime` would be more appropriate for such a time value without time zone.

Comment: I edited my post - JSON is generated from Postgres, `jsonb_build_object()` function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The String you're trying to parse, **2020-02-22T16:37:23**, doesn't end in **Z**. Instant expects this as it stands for **UTC**. It simply cannot be parsed. Concat the String with Z to resolve the issue.

```java
        String customInstant = "2020-02-22T16:37:23";

        System.out.println("Instant of: " + Instant.parse(customInstant.concat("Z")));
```

Comment: JSON is generated by Postgres function `jsonb_build_object()`. So I changed SQL query to `jsonb_build_object(
                        'recoveryId', r.recovery_id,
                        'startedAt', replace(concat(r.started_at, 'Z'), ' ', 'T'),` and it helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

One way to do this is to create a `Converter`.

```
public final class NoUTCInstant implements Converter<LocalDateTime, Instant> {
    @Override
    public Instant convert(LocalDateTime value) {
        return value.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    }
    @Override
    public JavaType getInputType(TypeFactory typeFactory) {
        return typeFactory.constructType(LocalDateTime.class);
    }
    @Override
    public JavaType getOutputType(TypeFactory typeFactory) {
        return typeFactory.constructType(Instant.class);
    }
}
```

Then annotate the field.

```
@JsonDeserialize(converter = NoUTCInstant.class)
private Instant startedAt;
```